# Android firebase register , current user null pointer exception when trying to get display name

Tags: java, android, firebase, nullpointerexception

I have the problem below , I have this sample code :
And when im trying to use this one --> "databaseRef.child(user.getDisplayName()).setValue(displayName);"
I get the error below. Anyone can explain me why this is happening? Seems pretty normal to me cant understand why the error is generated.

```
public void registerUser(final String displayName, String email, final String password){
        regAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser user=regAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                .setDisplayName(displayName).build();
                        user.updateProfile(profileUpdates);
                        databaseRef.push().child(user.getDisplayName()).setValue(displayName);
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                        Spannable errormes = new SpannableString("Registration Successful As User :" + displayName);
                        errormes.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, errormes.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                        error.setText(errormes);
                        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, login.class);
                        startActivity(loginIntent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        if(password.length()<6)
                            error.setText("Password too Short! Must be at least 6 characters long! \n Please provide different password.");
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error with registration!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        error.setText("     Error 110! User already exists! \n    Please provide different username!");
                        try {
                            throw task.getException();
                        } catch (FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException e) {
                            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
                        } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
                        } catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
                            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

    }
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument
>   'pathString' in child()
>                                                                                at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                at
>   com.myapp.RegisterActivity$2.onComplete(RegisterActivity.java:97)
>                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: `getCurrentUser()` can return null, and looks like it did

Comment: did you initialize the firebaseAuth `FirebaseAuth.getInstance();`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of your **databaseRef** value and where its pointing to.
Make sure data base reference does exist for databaseRef.child.
Looks like `user.getDisplayName()` is returning **NULL** hence its mapped to

```
databaseRef.child(NULL).setValue(displayName);
```

Try to print all the values in console or log and cross check with Firebase database on browser.

Also try updates with listener

```
user.updateProfile(profileUpdates).
    addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                            Log.d("Success", "Success");
                                                        }
                                                        });
```

Comment: Yea user.getDisplayName() is null but cant understand the reason ... Above of that there is the initialisation of user and setDisplayName.. so it should work right? 
It sets correctly  the display name but in the same method it seems it cannot get it.

databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UserNames:");

Comment: May be because your profile update script is not working as expected. Try this  firebaseUser.updateProfile(userProfileChangeRequest).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            Log.d("Success", "Success");
                                        }
                                    });

Comment: Check updated answer, as @cricket_007 suggested you dont need to get user name as you already have it the method with name displayName

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are setting the name, the trying to get the value using a method is concerning. You already have the value, so using a getter isn't needed.

Your user reference probably shouldn't be using a display name that's the key of the database, however. Especially if multiple users can have the same name. You probably meant something like

```
databaseRef.child(user.getUid()).setValue(displayName);
```

Or use a child key that cannot be null, as the error mentions

Also, not sure if that's necessary since you're already doing a profile update for the current user

Comment: Im using almost the same code on another activity and its working like that it creates a child on database with the user name , just it seems I cant get that username while register. Seems I have to somehow log in the user get the name and then disconnect him and prompt him into log in screen

Comment: The createUser method call assigns the current user, but they don't necessarily have a display name

Comment: Try getting that user object ID

Comment: It has a display name from the EditText its provided. The scripts works i mean on FireBase the user with DisplayName is added but inside this block it seems its not working ....

Comment: I added more to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Okey guys thank you everyone for the try. @cricket_007 made me think better. I already had the username so just changed this databaseRef.child(user.getDisplayName()).setValue(displayName); 
to this
databaseRef.push().child(displayName).setValue(null);
Cant understand why it fails to read the username when using user.getDisplayName() on the same block of code but it worked that way.